# Automatically play html video when in element becomes visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, scroll, viewport

Actually I just want to put this as a kind of Wiki, after breaking my fingers on this.

1. How to automatically start video when in viewport.
2. Most importantly: **Wordpress compatible solution** PURE JavaScript. No JQuery. Why? Because newbies like me have a hard time "enqueing" libraries into wordpress... When even just receiving a scroll event is hard...

Anyway, posting answer below:

Answer (score 1):

So - A straight forward, shortest solution is for creating a video on an html page, or indeed use a "raw HTML" element in WordPress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var video = null;
  var ended = false;

  function checkScroll()
  {
    if( video == null )
      return;
    var rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
    // console.log( rect.top, rect.bottom, window.innerHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight );
    var inViewPort = Math.abs( rect.top ) < window.innerHeight;
    if( inViewPort )
    {
      if( video.paused && ( ended == false ) )
      {
        video.play();
        video.addEventListener( 'ended', myHandler, false );
        function myHandler(e)
        {
          ended = true;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      video.currentTime = 0;
      ended = false;
    }
  }

  window.onload = function()
  {
    video = document.getElementById( 'rubi-second-video' );
    window.onscroll = function()
    {
      checkScroll();
    }
  }

  checkScroll();
```